# StatusItem menu doesn't open on hover

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've got an NSStatusItem with a menu. My problem is that when you click on for example the wifi icon, the menu appears. When I move to the right (on my mac the battery status item is there) the menu for the battery automatically appears. That's what I mean with "on hover". This behaviour is implemented in pretty much all status items and/or menu's. But my NSStatusItem doesn't implement this behaviour. I don't see an option in IB to "assign" this behaviour, so I started searching the web and all I can come up with is this:

[Status Item menus don't open on hover](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220094-status-item-menus-don-open-on-hover.html)

The "answer" here is everything but satisfying. So my question is: is this true? Aren't there any ways to create this behaviour without using private API's?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Frans

Comment: In my experience, it is true, and there is no public-API way around it, but it would be nice to have an authoritative answer.

Comment: Is there anyone with an authoritative answer? @Smilin Brian thnx for your comment.